# Posting limited fields with ExtJS 4.2.x REST on store update

Tags: rest, extjs, extjs4.2

We are trying to use ExtJS grid/forms and bind them with Store to perform REST operations.
Now as I was playing with extjs examples for restful api, I came across http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/restful/restful.html and tried editing a model to add a new field 'phone' in the list like below:

```
Ext.define('Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int',
        useNull: true
    }, 'email', 'first', 'last','phone'],
    validations: [{
        type: 'length',
        field: 'email',
        min: 1
    }, {
        type: 'length',
        field: 'first',
        min: 1
    }, {
        type: 'length',
        field: 'last',
        min: 1
    }]
});
```

As you can see "phone" is a new field added in fields list of a model and after adding that field while I was trying to perform any of the rest operation (PUT/POST) it was posting that field along with rest of the visible fields in grid. This is something I have not expected.

Is there anyway by which I can just post dirty fields (which are modified) and not all those exist in model with default store/rest manipulation way that ExtJS has provided?

Answer (score 2):

In the proxy writer definition you would want to use the writeAllFields param which will work for updates.  New model instances will send all fields.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Writer-cfg-writeAllFields